# Entity Framework making nullable unsigned int field's value as null while saving into database

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6, dbcontext, nullable

I'm having this weird problem where I try to save the value of an unsigned `nullable` field into a db using `Entity Framework 6` and it always sets the value as NULL in Db even when I send actual values to save. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

I have entity class:

```
[Table("Order")]
public class OrderForComparision
{
    [Key]
    public string TicketNumber { get; set; }
    public unint? OriginID { get; set; }
}
```

I have the table create query that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Order](
    [TicketNumber] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [OriginID] [bigint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_OrderId] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [TicketNumber] ASC
))
```

I update the table this way:

```
    try
    {
        using (var dbCon = GetDbContext())
        {
            var orderInDb = await dbCon.Orders.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.TicketNumber == order.TicketNumber);
            if (orderInDb == null)
            {
                orderInDb = new OrderForComparision
                {
                    TicketNumber = order.TicketNumber,
                    OriginID = order.OriginID ?? null,
                };
                dbCon.Orders.Add(orderInDb);
            }
            else
            {
                orderInDb.OriginID = order.OriginID ?? null;
            }
            await dbCon.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
```

I only see `NULL` in Db even when I pass value to this field. When I check the object while debugging, I see this:

```
ColumnName  Value   Type
OriginID    3823    uint?
```

I have tried:

`OriginID == null ? (uint?)null : order.OriginID.Value`,

`OriginID = order.OriginID.HasValue ? order.OriginID.Value : (uint?)null`

and

`OriginID = order.OriginID ?? null`. And nothing has worked for me yet. Could it be the issue with my Db or the way I'm saving? I just can't figure out this simple weird issue.

Comment: Try OriginID = order.OriginID.HasValue?order.OriginID.Value:null;

Comment: @ManishKumar `order.OriginID ?? null` basically is the shorthand way of saying what you're saying.

Answer (score 0):

You always send null value thats why it is always saving null value.

Change

```
OriginID?? null
```

to

```
OriginID==null??null: OriginID
```

Comment: No, I'm not always sending null value. And I have already did this: `OriginID == null ? (uint?)null : order.OriginID.Value` which doesn't work. I also tried `OriginID = order.OriginID.HasValue ? order.OriginID.Value : (uint?)null` which is basically the same as `OriginID = order.OriginID ?? null`. And nothing has worked for me yet.

Comment: Then check order.OriginID.value==null??

Comment: EF doesn't support unsigned data types does it? Try changing the model to a long?